# Generating SQL script from an Excel File (with multiple sheets)

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba

How can we generate SQL scripts `(Delete and Update)` based on a column, `say A`, value in `Excel sheet`.

Logic runs like this:

1. If value in A column is Yes, generate a Delete SQL statement for every row which as value in Column A as Yes, otherwise generate a Update SQL statement.
2. Generated SQL script should be automatically saved in a text file/notepad.

Comment: Hi @Beginner, this is simple string joining in excel based on a few conditions.  Having done a quick google there are several examples on how to combine text/cells etc based on conditions.  What have you tried so far?  Can you please attach/show your attempts?  For future questions, might be worth looking at https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: If it is a one-time job, You can import excel data in the SQL Server in the table and write a query to generate delete and update the script or you can do this in excel itself using formula.

Comment: The idea to create a sql statement file to update a server is not a so stupid idea as it sounds. Usually they connext with ODBC which is very slow. If i have to uses something like that its way faster to create a command file and then use just ONE call to push it into the server. And the guy seems to be a newbee - let learn him by easy steps. On a text file he can watch whats going wrong by some online sql tester instead to nuke the whole company infrastructure on the first day ;)

Comment: Hi All, Many thanks for your comments/suggestions, but let me explain what I have tried so far:

Comment: Approach 1: Upload Excel file to a temp table in SQL Server (which can be dropped later). 2. Select data/rows on the basis of given condition. 3. Generate SQL command for selected rows. 4. Export it to a notepad .sql file which can be used later to update tables.

Comment: To achieve this I tried this command: SELECT * INTO EXCEL_IMPORT
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0; Database=C:\Users\5004208\Desktop\EGYPT\General_Contact_MJ.xlsx; HDR=YES; IMEX=1',
'SELECT * FROM [PRODUCT$]');   but got the following error: Msg 7403, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0" has not been registered. And we can't make any changes to server to accomodate the above query as per organisation protocol.

Comment: APPROACH 2. I tried BULK INSERT first and later same steps can be followed as mentioned in Approach 1 above:    BULK INSERT TEMP_TABLE FROM  "C:\Users\5004208\Desktop\EGYPT\General_Contact_MJ.xlsx"
 WITH 
            (FIELDTERMINATOR  = ''''
            ,FIRSTROW=1)  but got below error: Msg 4834, Level 16, State 4, Line 12
You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement. Again, permission cannot be granted for the reason cited above. Now I was just wondering how many other ways are there to achieve this including VBA, but it should be an automated solution not a manual one.

Answer (score 0):

1. ask google how to use vba
2. ask google to find out how to read append and delete text files :)
3. ask google for SQL tutorials
4. as google how to execute sql files for your server

To give you a kick start - this works in principle like this:

```
Function filewrite(ByRef FILE, ByRef TEXT As String) As long
  ERR.CLEAR
  On Error Resume Next
  Dim FF As Long
  FF = FreeFile()
  On Error Resume Next
  Open FILE For Output As #FF
  Print #FF, TEXT
  Close #FF
  filewrite = ERR.NUMBER
  On Error GoTo 0
  ERR.CLEAR
End Function

sub create_delete_statements(tablename)
   dim SQL as  string
   Dim WS As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim WB As Excel.Workbook
```

open xyz.xls if needed

```
   Set WB = AP.Workbooks.Open("Unknown.xls")
```

chooses a workbook from "Unknown.xls"
this will work also same way if you want to use "Sheet2"
eg Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet2")

```
   Set WS = WB.Worksheets("Sheet1") 

   for i=0 to 10
        if ws.Cell(i,1).value=-1 then ''use "Sheet1"
             databaseid=ws.Cell(i,2).value  
             SQL=SQL & "DELETE FROM TABLE " & tablename & "where id =" & databaseid & ";" & vblf
        endif
   next 
   dim FN as string
   on error resume next
   err.clear
   fn="commands.sql"
```

kill /delete the old sql file if it exists

```
   if dir(fn)<>"" kill(fn)
```

pump your statements out

```
   fresult= filewrite(fn,SQL) 
   if err.number + fresult <> 0 msgbox "Something went wrong on file out"
end sub
```

Have fun :)